# Заменить фрагмент на странице thymeleaf

Tags: java, jquery, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Имеется очень много страниц в которых присутствует повторяющиеся фрагменты типа head, footer и т.п и лишь изменяется контент. Такой подход, на мой взгляд, не продуктивный, поэтому я создал заготовку блоков:

```
<th:block th:fragment="idea" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <!-- Контент-1 -->
</th:block>

<th:block th:fragment="edit" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <!-- Контент-2 -->
</th:block>
```

Создал контроллер для обработки запросов

**@Controller:**

```
@GetMapping("/idea")
public String getIdeas(Model model){

    model.addAttribute("message", "some content");

    return "common/idea :: idea";
}

@GetMapping("/edit")
public String getEdit(Model model){

    model.addAttribute("message", "some content");

    return "common/idea :: edit";
}
```

Общий шаблон, можно сказать скелет

**HTML Template:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Главная</title>
    <th:block th:insert="common/page :: head"/>
</head>

<body>

    <!-- Header-->
    <th:block th:insert="common/page :: header"/>

    <!-- Content -->
    <div class="content" id="replace">
        
        *Тут хочу вставлять фрагменты*

    </div><!-- /.content -->

    <!-- Footer -->
    <th:block th:insert="common/page :: footer"/>

</body>
</html>
```

Написал скрипт для обновления блока в скелете

**JQuery:**

```
$('#someHref').on('click', function (event){
    $("#replace").load("/idea");
});
```

Но при таком подходе у меня не загружается ничего кроме данного куска(должен быть еще head, header, footer)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Однако если я добавлю в jq preventDefault() то не буду получать ответ от сервера, но увижу обновление блока без новой модели.

Я бы хотел понять с помощью чего лучше выполнять такие действия(замена блоков фрагментами при обращении к разным маппингам).

Answer (score 1):

Обычно веб-сайты имеют общие компоненты страницы, такие как верхний колонтитул, нижний колонтитул, меню и, возможно, многие другие. Эти компоненты страницы могут использоваться как в одном, так и в разных макетах. Существует два основных стиля организации макетов в проектах: включающий стиль ([Thymeleaf Standard Layout System](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#template-layout)) и иерархический стиль ([Thymeleaf Layout Dialect](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/layouts.html#thymeleaf-layout-dialect)). Оба стиля можно легко использовать с Thymeleaf, не теряя при этом его самой большой ценности: естественного создания шаблонов.

Конкретно вам надо посмотреть иерархический стиль шаблонов. Линки к ресурсам на английском языке, но Google переведёт контент. То что я вижу на русском языке:  [Thymeleaf: пользовательский макет диалекта](https://www.codeflow.site/ru/article/thymeleaf-spring-layouts) выглядит неплохо.